# Google social login button doesn't show

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-signin

I am working on a FTW template and I added the google login logic into it from some commits from ftw github. Now I need to add the google client id into my `.env` file, but in the template I see it's located in a `.env-template` file and is empty. When I put it there, nothing happens, and I don't know why.

This is how the client id is used in my js files :

```
const showGoogleLogin = !!process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID;
```

This is how the `env-template` part looks like :

```
// Social logins && SSO
// If the app or client id is not set the auhtentication option is not shown in FTW
```

REACT_APP_FACEBOOK_APP_ID=
FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET=

```
REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=
```

Should I move these variables in my `.env` file ? Because I did and it still doesn't work, nothing shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move it to the `.env` file (or any other valid `.env.*` extension).

And then you have to stop and start your react app again so it takes new changes of that new environment variables.